# A first chance exception

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, visual-studio-debugging

This seems different from all the other messages about first chance exceptions :)

I'm trying to track down an occasional exception that gets thrown in the serial port inbound data handler. When it fires, the stack trace doesn't show any of my code- it's all stuff inside standard assemblies starting with System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(). Since it's outside any of my own code, I can't handle it and know nothing until it hits CurrentDomain_UnhandledException on the way down.

I'm starting a thread to handle incoming serial comms. Since the serial port is a USB device that can accidentally be unplugged and the port then goes away, when there's a problem I kill the thread and start afresh, enumerating the ports and querying them to pick the device up again when it comes back.

In the output, I'm seeing several "A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException". Some of them are in MS code. I'd like to be able to break at each one so I can confirm it's being handled, and not swallowed somewhere. However, when I tick the "System.Threading" thrown box in the Debug->Exceptions menu, VS never breaks. Even when I disable "Just my code", which I assume broadens the scope of the debugger.

Does anyone know of a third thing I'm missing that will make VS break on these exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

to break on first chance exceptions you could do this in visual c++ 2010
go to debug->exceptions and in c++ exceptions check the check box for std::exception i think this worked for me it was a while back